# Add groovy to target platform

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, p2, target-platform

I'm looking for a way to add groovy to my target platform. But I'm not looking for groovy IDE-Support, because I just want to use some classes (especially Binding and GroovyShell) to execute dynamic scripts during runtime. So I don't need the whole eclipse plugin to be added to the target platform.

Is there a p2 repository for the current groovy jar? Or do I have to download the jar manually and force it in my target platform?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use one of the existing p2 repos for Groovy-Eclipse and just install the appropriate groovy feature.

Here is the repo for e4.3:

```
http://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/e4.3/
```

You can install the feature (eg- org.codehaus.groovy21.feature) or the plugin (eg- org.codehaus.groovy).  You can install the plugin directly if you use the [p2 director application](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Director_application).

Be aware that the groovy plugin is not the same as the groovy-all jar since we provide a patch on top of the groovy compiler, but these changes should not affect the behavior of the compiler.